# Problem with <a> & Positioning

Tags: html, href

On [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/fitness/) the space between the left column and the title is too large. I think this is because the img at the top of the left column has an `<a href=""></a>`. Is there any way to make the img on the left line up with the img on the right (which is at the correct hight)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column has an empty `<a href="http://www.glamourunderground.com/?p=217" target="_blank">&nbsp;<p></p>
</a>` tag and an empty `<p>` tag, which are pushing the column's contents down. The simple solution would be to remove the tags, since they're empty and the `<a>` isn't  clickable anwyways.

Comment: @domsterr @D Thank you :) that was the problem. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

You have all of this between your title and your image:

```
<div class="date">
</div>
</div>
<div class="cover">
<div class="entry">
<div class="col1"><a href="http://www.glamourunderground.com/?p=217">&nbsp;<p></p>
</a><p><a href="http://www.glamourunderground.com/?p=217"></a></p>
```

Might want to clean it up and your problem will probably be solved. Especially the `&nbsp;` part.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem isn't the `<a>` tag at all, but the empty `<p>` tag and non-breaking space `&nbsp;` inside:

```
<a href=".../?p=217" target="_blank">&nbsp;<p></p>
</a>
```

Remove those and the two columns should line up.

EDIT: And as others have noted, you don't need this anchor at all and it should probably be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Each DIV has a hard code value for the TOP css property. Reduce each value by 85px.